# Having trouble with Json formatting when usign Fluentd to send logs to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, fluentd

I am using Fluentd plugin to send logs to BigQuery, but the BQ plugin seems to change the ":" to "=>" when sendign the data to BigQuery.
The logs arrive in BigQuery with key=>value instead of key:value formatting.
I have the following match definitions in td-agent.conf

```
<match bq.*.*>
  type copy
  deep_copy true
  <store>
    type bigquery   
    auth_method json_key
    json_key /home/fereshteh/keys/LL-POC-9081311ba6a0.json    
    project my-poc
    dataset MY_POC
    table   LogMessage     
    auto_create_table true
    field_string body,header
#  buffer_chunk_limit    
#  buffer_chunk_records_limit 300  
    buffer_queue_limit 10240         
    num_threads 16
#   flush_interval  1
    buffer_type file
    buffer_path /var/log/td-agent/buffer/bq
  </store>
  <store>
    type file
    path /var/log/td-agent/bq-logtextmsg.log
  </store>
</match>
```

Using "copy" feature, I was able to verify the source part is working correctly and that the copied logs do show the correct formatting of the json logs, key:value.
However, in BigQuery they show up as key=>value.
Any suggestions on how to change that to use ":"? 
BigQuery json_extract functions doesn't like "=>" and expects ":"s.
Thanks.

Comment: This happens if the value of a key is a json blob. Here is a log as was saved in bq-logtextmsg.log in the copy section:
{"body":{"asset_id":"00000000","loc_id":"76fd-7e32","sender_id":"8d512d0f .......    }   , and here is the log as shows up in BigQuery:
"body" field value: {"asset_id"=>"00000000", "loc_id"=>"76fd-7e32", "sender_id"=>"....... }